# How to store a hashed password to database?

Tags: python, mysql, bcrypt, password-encryption, password-hash

I'm using `Python 3` and `mysql.connector` module. I could not store the hased password to the database.

Here is my code:

```
import bcrypt
import base64, hashlib
import mysql.connector

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**Connect)
        self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor()

        pw = "Test123!"
        password=pw.encode('utf-8')
        
        hash_pass = bcrypt.hashpw(base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(password).digest()),bcrypt.gensalt())
        print(hash_pass)

        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (password) VALUE ('%s')" % (hash_pass))
        self.cnx.commit()

test()
```

When I run the `INSERT` statement, the error occurred:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$2b$12$2Jo8.yam0VU5IKQxMa4EV.ReuFGeG43wmzbrFDsT5Pr5c8L2rmlP6'')' at line 1
```

**Noted**: My datatype for `password` is `CHAR(96)`

I appreciate your help.

Comment: please read the manual for secure passwords https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php and look lalso at thementinoend function, which a good excplantion how to use them

Comment: What does bcrypt.hashpw return?  Is it ascii?  UTF-8?  or Binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use query parameters instead of string-formatting.

```
// WRONG
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (password) VALUE ('%s')" % (hash_pass))

// RIGHT
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (password) VALUE (%s)", (hash_pass,))
```

Both methods use `%s` as a placeholder, which is kind of confusing because it looks like it's doing the same thing. But the latter is not doing simple string substitution. It makes the value safe for the SQL query, either by escaping special characters, or by doing true query parameters, keeping the value separate until after the query has been parsed.